# Magento 1 : How to fetch the Customer Group Prices of Catalogue Prices (Promotional Rules) Prices of Group Products?

Tags: grouped-products, promotions, magento1.9.4.4

Let's have I have **10 Grouped products** and setup the multiple **Promotional Rules** for different Customer Groups.

**Rule 1 :**
Conditions met X

Actions - `Retailer` => get can the 5% discount

**Rule 2 :**
Conditions met Y

Actions - `Retailer` => get can the 7% discount

**Rule 3:**
Conditions met X

Actions - `Wholesaler` => get can the 10% discount

**Rule 4 :**
Conditions met Y

Actions - `Wholesaler` => get can the 14% discount

How to fetch the final price of all Grouped Products. No tax in the game.

Settings are as it is what Magento 1 provides.